# Label and non-plain text arguments

Tags: labels

I have a custom macro:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\includefigure{mo}{
  ...
  \caption{#2}
  \label{fig:#2}
}
```

The optional argument is used for the caption and the label. The problem is that when I have parts of this argument formatted like `\includefigure{pic}[Hi \textit{there}!]` I get errors like  "Missing \endcsname inserted." since `\label` does not allow arguments with commands in it.

Is there a meta-command like `\plaintext` so I could use `\label{\plaintext{fig:#2}}` in my command and then `\includefigure{pic}[Hi \textit{there}!]` would result in `\label{fig:Hi there!}`?

Or maybe there is an alternative for label.

Comment: A label is meant to be something to help you create refs: when are you adding formatting to it in the first place?

Comment: Because I'm reusing the #2 argument for \caption and \label. I don't want an additional argument only for the \label since it would be redundant to have \includefigure{pic}[Hi \textit{there}!][Hi there!]

Comment: I think this is an attempt at getting rid of the formatting, to automatically generate labels. But using the caption for the label sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: using a separate label isn't redundant, it is the main point of the cross referencing mechanism, you can re-order the figures so the number changes, and edit your caption text, while not needing to edit every place that references the figure if you use a short symbolic label that is unconnected with any of those typesetting features.

Comment: The advantage you describe is clear to me but I still prefer having identical captions and labels and having both set automatically :)

Comment: @user764754 What do you do for `\ref`? Are you *really* wanting to use `\ref{Hi \textit{there}}`?

Comment: For \ref it would be perfect to use plain text like \ref{fig:Hi there!}.

Answer (score 5):

The caption text can be converted to a safe string for the `\label` system by converting to hex code, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfescape}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\make@hex@label}[1]{%
  \def\hex@label{#1}%
  \@onelevel@sanitize\hex@label
  \EdefEscapeHex\hex@label{\hex@label}%
}
\newcommand*{\hexlabel}[1]{%
  \@bsphack
    \make@hex@label{#1}%
    \label{\hex@label}%
  \@esphack
}
\newcommand*{\hexref}[1]{%
  \make@hex@label{#1}%
  \ref{\hex@label}%
}
\newcommand*{\hexpageref}[1]{%
  \make@hex@label{#1}%
  \pageref{\hex@label}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\figurecaption}[1]{%
  \caption{#1}%
  \hexlabel{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\figurecaption{Hi \textit{there}!}
\end{figure}
See figure \hexref{Hi \textit{there}!}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Disadvantage:** Warnings show the hex string, e.g.:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `4869205C746578746974207B74686572657D21' on page 1 undefined on input line 35.
```

Comment: This is quite nice and probably the closest to what I want. Thanks!